# git preventing checkout due to --skip-worktree changes

Tags: git

So, here's what I did:

1. Make changes to DebugConstants.cs
2. Commit some (but not all) of the changes, leaving the other changes unstaged
3. Run 'git update-index --skip-worktree Core/DebugConstants.cs'
4. Attempt to check-out a different branch - fails.

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
```

```
git checkout feature/my-branch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        Core/DebugConstants.cs
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

'git status' says there aren't any uncommitted changes. 'get checkout' says I can't change branches until I get rid of my uncommitted changes.

So... what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course I figure it out minutes after posting the Question...

```
git update-index --skip-worktree Core/DebugConstants.cs
git reset head --hard
git update-index --no-skip-worktree Core/DebugConstants.cs
```

Comment: This is not answering how to checkout to the other branch keeping those changes. Didn't you lose them by running: git reset head --hard ?

Comment: @saccodd that's true. In my case, though, that's fine - DebugConstants is a simple file that contains things like the username of the developer. If you really needed to save them, you could either commit (instead of reset hard) or else just copy them into notepad to paste later. In general, though, any file under --skip-worktree is not going to track changes, so in many cases you won't care about changes.